# Error:(27, 0) Project with path ':library' could not be found in project ':app'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, libs

I have copied [this](https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect/tree/master/library) `library` folder in root of project but always getting:

```
Error:(27, 0) Project with path ':library' could not be found in project ':app'.
<a href="openFile:/home/oreo/Projects/RippleSample/app/build.gradle">Open File</a>
```

Here is the Project structure:

```
RippleSample
   > .gradle
   > .idea
   > app
   > gradle
   > library [just imported]
```

Comment: Please add your build.gradle files and your settings.gradle file.

Answer (score 83):

Create a `settings.gradle` file in the root of your project and add

```
include ':library'
```

to the file. Just like this image:

[image]

Answer (score 29):

In your `RippleSample/settings.gradle` you have to add:

```
include ':app' , ':library'
```

Answer (score -2):

Put the  jar into the libs folder

Right click it and hit 'Add as library'

Ensure that compile files('libs/jar') is in your build.gradle file

Do a clean build

Comment: right answer for adding .jar libraries ( not on this case )